# Building select clause for Dataframe in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of columns and I need to build a Column object which contains all the column names so that I can query that as select.

For eg something like this.. this is for AND case though

```
for(int i =1;i<tablecols.size();i++){
    col = col.and(new org.apache.spark.sql.Column(tablecols.get(i).getTclName()));
  }
  initialDataFrame.select(col);
```

Comment: They are just string values . I have to make another data frame from the original one with different sequence. So I want to make a select expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
List<String> tablecols = Arrays.asList("first_col", "second_col");
List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();

for (String tablecol : tablecols) {
    columns.add(new Column(tablecol));
}

initialDataFrame.select(columns.toArray(new Column[columns.size()]));
```